# Select with date range in MySQL not working after New Year

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am using the following select statement to get the number of entries in a database within the last `x` days, however it doesn't seem to work after the turn of the new year.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM entries WHERE type = 'xxxxx' AND email = 'xx@xxx.com' AND date_created >= CURRENT_DATE-'30 days'
```

The reason I'm using a string for '30 days' is because this is executed as a prepared statement from a PHP script. Is there a reason that this won't traverse correctly into previous years?

The value for 30 days and 7 days is the same, even though there are more entries contained within 7 days than 30.

Comment: what is the type of date_created?

Comment: It's a `DATETIME`. Fixed this by using `DATE_SUB` function - about to add an answer. This seems like a bug in MySQL though...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the SQL statement to the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM entries WHERE type = 'xxxxx' AND email = 'xx@xxx.com' AND date_created >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

This still works with prepared statements (by replacing 30 with ?).

I think this is a bug with MySQL so I'll submit a report, unless anyone can think of a logical reason why the original statement didn't work?